# Formatting data in a new column through an update query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two columns "POI Year" and "POI SeqNum" these look like:

```
|POI Year|POI SeqNum|new_col
|2005    |1         |
|2006    |17        |
```

I'm trying to return the year and seqnum but I also need to add `'30'` as a string and a `'.'` so I'm trying to formulate an update query where the end result will look like this:

```
|POI Year|POI SeqNum|new_col
|2005    |1         |2005.301
|2006    |17        |2006.317
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding 300 to the SeqNum could be the trick.

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET new_col = CONCAT("POI Year", '.', 300+"POI SeqNum")
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
select 
  poi_year,
  poi_seqnum,
  to_char(poi_year, '9999') || '.' || 
    to_char(300 + poi_seqnum, '999') as new_col
from my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `to_char()` to format the number with leading zeros and then concatenate that with the year:

```
select poi_year,
       poi_seqnum, 
       poi_year||'.'||to_char(poi_seqnum, 'FM00')
from the_table;
```